# cast reflected result from object to list<TDest> where TDest is enum

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I cast a reflected result
from object to `List<TDynamicType>`?

```
Type tSource = item.SourceType;     //enum
Type tDest = item.DestinationType;  //enum

MethodInfo method = typeof(EnumConverters).GetMethod("GetEnumValues");
MethodInfo methodGenericSource = method.MakeGenericMethod(tSource);
object enumsSource = methodGenericSource.Invoke(null, null);

// i need to convert enumsSource to List<tDest> (where tDest is enum)
List<tDest> list = ???
```

Is there a reflection function like "getResultGeneric" or "getResultOfType"?

Comment: You mean something like.  `List<tDest> list = sourceList.Cast<tDest>().ToList()` ?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes but i've not a list, i've an object... (and type of list is resolved at runtime)

Comment: You cannot cast to a type that is unknown at compile time. What do you want to do with `list`, why do you require a cast?

Comment: @giacomo If the *actual runtime type of the object* is not a list type at all, casting won't help you. Or are you saying that you *do* have a list, but the *reference to it* is declared as `object`? If that's the case, you may have to cast to non-generic `System.Collecitons.IList`, and then cast the items separately to something useful -- perhaps an interface that all potential `TDynamicType`s are known to implement.

Comment: If you don't need to add items , and if any value of `tDest` is can be assumed to implement some interface `IWhatever` which *is* known at compile time, you can cast to `IEnumerable<IWhatever>`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i don't need to cast it to a list<object> but to a  list<enum> (custom/public enums) but casting to 

                    List<Enum> enumList = enumsSource as List<Enum>; //give me null

Comment: @giacomo You don’t need any list, you need ienumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Could try casting to `IList<TDynamicType>` like so: `var list = sourceList.Cast<IList<TDynamicType>>().ToList()`

Comment: i have no sourceList, it's justa an object

Comment: Okay.. I saw the solution you posted, I think you could also try the [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads)

Answer (score 0):

i've solved in this way, castin object to iEnumerableOfInteger (casting as listOfObject give null), and then parsing it.

```
                Type tSource = item.SourceType;     //enum
                Type tDest = item.DestinationType;  //enum

                MethodInfo method = typeof(EnumConverters).GetMethod("GetEnumValues");
                MethodInfo methodGenericSource = method.MakeGenericMethod(tSource);
                object objEnumsSource = methodGenericSource.Invoke(null, null);

                //var listObj = (IEnumerable<object>)objEnumsSource;//throw
                var listInt = (IEnumerable<int>)objEnumsSource;
                foreach (var i in listInt)
                {
                    if (!Enum.IsDefined(tSource, i))
                        throw new ApplicationException($"!Enum.IsDefined({tSource.FullName}, {i})");

                    var o = Enum.ToObject(tSource, i);
                    var e = Convert.ChangeType(o, tSource);
                }
```

Comment: You do not need _both_ `Enum.ToObject` and `Convert.ChangeType` in the end.